# Redirect entire Wordpress site good practice

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have cloned an entire wordpress site - lets call that x.com. I installed the clone on a new site - lets call the y.com.

No I need to make a redirect in my .htaccess. I try with this which gave me a 500 internal error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://y.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So how am I making a proper redirect where x.com/product/cream is redirect to y.com/product/cream etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block is what causes a wide range of urls to be handled by the Wordpress engine. You should have this block only in the VirtualHost or the .htaccess file for `y.com`, the website where you now host Wordpress.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The second block is the redirect. You want to only redirect on `x.com`, so put this block only in the VirtualHost or .htaccess file from `x.com`.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://y.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Keep in mind that you should **only use temporary redirects (302) when testing**, because permanent redirects (301) get cached by the browser, which causes the browser to lookup the result in its own cache rather than asking the server for a new redirect. When you are happy with the result, change the rule to a permanent redirect by changing `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. So I will delete the first block and insert the `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://y.com/$1 [R,L]` . That block will redirect every single page from the old to the new, right? `x.com/products/cream redirect to `y.com/products/cream` etc